# CakePHP - 'AuthComponent' with a different model name (not 'User')

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I want to use *[AuthComponent](http://api.cakephp.org/class/auth-component)* in CakePHP with a model (and its corresponding table) named Admin ('admins' table in the database). I've used  **$this->Auth->userModel = 'Admin';** as the documenation says in the **BeforeFilter()** function of the **app_controller**, to indicate that I'm not using the deafult model **User**.

However, either I'm doing it in the wrong place or there's something else that needs to be done, because I can't make the authentication to work (the **login** function in my **admins_controller.php**). The rest of functions work well (for example the **add** function).

If I use the name **User** for my model with a **users** table, it works perfectly. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: It can also be done with an array option of `'userModel' => 'Admin'` when you add `Auth` component to your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you call `parent::beforeFilter()` in your `AdminController::beforeFilter()`.